# MailKit log file is empty

Tags: c#, mailkit, mimekit

I'm developing an application ASP.NET, using MailKit v.2.4.1, I'm trying to use ProtocolLogger, but the log file is always empty. This is the code I use:

```
 using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(new ProtocolLogger(Server.MapPath("~/Log/SMTP.log"))))
 using (ImapClient imap = new ImapClient(new ProtocolLogger(Server.MapPath("~/Log/IMAP.log"))))
       {
        smtp.Connect(bParametri.GetParametro("ServerSMTP").Valore,int.Parse(bParametri.GetParametro("PortaSMTP").Valore), true);
                                if (smtp.IsConnected)
                                {
                                    smtp.Authenticate(bParametri.GetParametro("UserSMTP").Valore, bParametri.GetParametro("PasswordSMTP").Valore);
                                    if (smtp.IsAuthenticated)
                                    {
                                        smtp.Send(emailO);
                                        smtp.Disconnect(true);}}}
```

smtp.Connect generates an SSPI error, but the log file is always empty.

Comment: The connect has to work for you to see log file.  Most mail servers require using default credentials which are in the user mail settings on the client machine.  The From account and user account has to be the same.

Comment: @jdweng, how'd we log the output of smtp client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ProtocolLogger doesn't log SSL/TLS negotiation information because that all happens at a lower level inside .NET's SslStream that MailKit does not have access to.

MailKit's ProtocolLogger *ONLY* logs SMTP, POP3 and/or IMAP commands.

Comment: How'd we access the smtp logs then if an email not being sent?